# Django Removing url and view gives NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am facing a problem with the urls and views and a No Reverse Match to an removed page. My project is a small CRM. At first I had only a list of customers. So my page had the hierarchy:

**Customer list (home.html)
-Customer details
-Edit one customer**

Now, I want to enlarge the system, that means each customer get subsidiaries:

**Customer list (home.html)
-Customer subsidiaries list
-Details to one customer subsidiary
-Edit one customer subsidiary**

My Question is: I have inserted in a first simple step a subsidiary page and linked it from home. But now I get an Reverse Match Error on home html on the edit page? Don't get why. I have even removed all links to edit.

Nowhere else I have a usage of the edit page. Why do I get a Reverse Match error? Does Django saveformer relations? Do you have any hint?

**error**

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'edit_customer' not found. 'edit_customer' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^customerSubs/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.customer_subs, name='customer_subs'),
    url(r'^customerDetails/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.customer_details, name='customer_details'),
#   url(r'^customerDetails/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.edit_customer, name='edit_customer'),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'customers': customers})

def customer_subs(request, pk):
    customerSubs = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'customerSubs.html', {'customerSubs':  customerSubs})    


def customer_details(request, pk):
    customerDetails = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'customerDetails.html', {'customerDetails':  customerDetails})    

#def edit_customer(request, pk):
#   customerDataSet = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
# .....
```

**Home.html**

```
<tbody>
      {% for customer in customers %}
        <tr>
          <td>
        <a href="{% url 'customer_subs' customer.pk %}">{{ customer.customerName }}</a>
         <small class="text-muted d-block">MID: {{ customer.MId }}</small>
        </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

As asked the part of

**customerSubs.html**

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<!--        <td class="align-middle"><a href="{% url 'edit_customer' customerDetails.pk %}">{{ customerDetails.customerName }}</a>-->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please update question with the error traceback.

Comment: Could you please add the code for `customerSubs.html` ? I suspect there's still a `{% url %}` call in there that's pointed to your (no longer present) edit view

Comment: @PeteTinkler: Yes, you are right. But the funny thing is, that I have commented it out with <!-- .... --> Somewhere was for sure an error in code. I have deleted everything in it and now it works.

Comment: you've commented it out with HTML comment syntax- but this is a Django function- run while rendering the page template. you would have to use the DJANGO template language commenting syntax `{#   #}` to comment it out.

Comment: @PeteTinkler Thank you lot. I have learned something. Only bad that I learned it the hard way :-)

Comment: If you add that html template to the question for posterity I'll post this as an answer

Comment: @PeteTinkler updated question with relevant part of `customerSubs.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `customerSubs.html` template you have commented out the call to Django's URL resolver using HTML commenting syntax- which means that as far as Django is concerned when it comes to render the template the `{% url %}` call to the removed url and view is still parsed. If you comment it out using Django's template commenting syntax `{# ... #}` Django will skip over it at rendering time and won't throw the error.